# Unable to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: configuration, onion-services, onion-routing, browsers

I am trying to setup onion hidden service and i am using xampp default apache web server.
I setup everything correctly and got my hostname and private key but the main problem i am getting is that i am unable to reach my web server localhost in tor browser while in chrome or firefox if i type localhost or 127.0.0.1 it show me my index file in htdocs of xampp folder.
So how i can open my localhost in my tor browser and how my hostname can serve it.